# Clearing workspace and sourcing script in one go in rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way (shortcut or button or so) that allows me to clear the workspace and then source the current `.r` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a non-ideal but will-do solution myself. Using the RStudio shortcut manager, you can define a shortcut to clean the workspace. I bound this to `CTRL+SHIFT+X`, such that it is close to the shortcut for sourcing the script, `CTRL+SHIFT+S`. However, clearing the workspace has a warning pop-up, so eventually, the routine becomes `CTRL+SHIFT+X - ENTER - CTRL+SHIFT+S`.

Answer (score 1):

You can prior to sourcing your .R file do a few cleanups

Clean your workspace environment `rm(list = ls())`

Clear the plots tab `if(!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off()`

Clear the console `cat("\014")` (same as the shortcut `Ctrl+L`)

Comment: Indeed, this works, but I was hoping to get a shortcut that can do it all at once (without having to use the console)